# north east lines pattern on function using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

Patterns works nice with plane line made with a simple \draw command, when the \draw is a plot function the pattern does not work as I espect

This is my code

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\begin{document}

    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, font=\large]   
        \fill[pattern=north east lines] (-5,0) rectangle (5,-0.1);
        \draw[line width=0.5pt](-5,0)-- (5,0);  
        \draw[line width=0.5pt, fill, pattern=north east lines] plot[domain=-5:5] (\x,{0.6*\x/sqrt((\x)^2+1)-2});           
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

And a preview

[image]

Comment: it's not clear (to me) what you want to achieve, or what you were expecting.

Comment: I want the pattern of the function to behave the same as the pattern in the straight line.

Comment: The pattern to be below the curve?

Comment: Yes, I want that one looks like the top one (pattern I mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to close the region you want to fill with the pattern. In this case you need to draw another parallel curve below the first one.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, font=\large]   
        \fill[pattern=north east lines] (-5,0) rectangle (5,-0.1);
        \draw[line width=0.5pt](-5,0)-- (5,0);  
        \fill[pattern=north east lines] plot[domain=-5:5] (\x,{0.6*\x/sqrt((\x)^2+1)-2}) --++ (0,-0.1) --
                                        plot[domain=-5:5] (-\x,{-0.6*\x/sqrt((\x)^2+1)-2.1}) -- cycle; % <-- this closes the region to fill
        \draw[line width=0.5pt] plot[domain=-5:5] (\x,{0.6*\x/sqrt((\x)^2+1)-2});           
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!